# How do I get a power set in a specific order?

Tags: algorithm, set

there some solutions for calculating a power set, but these I found on google doesn't give the power set in the order, which I need it. 
For example, if I want the power set of `(1,2,3,4)` common algorithms provide me with a power set in the 
following order:

```
()
(1)
(2)
(1 2)
(3)
(1 3)
(2 3)
(1 2 3)
(4)
(1 4)
(2 4)
(1 2 4)
(3 4)
(1 3 4)
(2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
```

But what I need is the following order:

```
()
(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(3,4)
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,4)
(2,3,4)
(1,2,3,4)
```

Because the number of elements can be quite high, it is not possible to calculate the whole power set and order it afterwards.

Has anyone some idea?

Comment: If you're trying to implement this in a particular programming language, it might help avoid improper closing if you'd tag it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the combinations in order by length. In Python you can write:

```py
import itertools

def subsets(iterable):
    "Generate the subsets of elements in the iterable, in order by length."
    items = list(iterable)
    for k in xrange(len(items) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(items, k):
            yield subset

>>> list(subsets([1,2,3,4]))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n/127856#127856) for an overview of algorithms that generate combinations. (Or you can look at Raymond Hettinger's Python implementation, [itertoolsmodule.c lines 2026f](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9a0b6c07b488/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2026).)

Answer (score 4):

(You should give some details about the algorithms you found on google...)

But you can process this way:

**first :** Create a function that generate all the power sets of length n of a given ordered set:

here is a possible pseudo code for this function:

```
set={a1, ...ap} //is an ordered set
define f( set , n):
   result = {}
   count=1
   for element in set :
         set.pop(element)
         result.append( { f(set,n-1).AppendtoAllInfirstPosition(element) }) // not sure if I write this well, but you process recursively, poping the sorted value one by one a1...ap and using f(popped set, n-1) you append the sets 
   if length(set)=n:
         return set //you initialise the recurence. the above loop will stop when len(popped(set))=n-1
   return result
```

**Second :** Once you done this you just determinate :

```
f(set,i) for i in range(len(set)) and you will get your ordered power set.
```

Hope this works and it helps

Answer (score 2):

If the initial set has N numbers the power set will contain 2^N elements. I suggest the following

**Algorithm:**

Sequently generate all subsets of inital set in order of increasing their number of elements. This can be done, for example, by considering all permutations of an array, consisting of `k` ones and `n-k` zeroes (this is also called ***mask***). Each mask describes a unique subset - we just pick the elements standing on the positions which are set to `1`. By this we will get (print, save or whatever is needed) all the subsets ordered by increasing their size, if equal then by order of elements appearing in the initial set.

**Complexity:**
Iterating `2^N` masks and looking at `N` positions in each will lead us to `O( N * 2^N )` complexity.

**Implementation:**
Here is my implementation in C++, using `std::next_permutation` to generate all masks with fixed number of `ones`. It reads a set of integers from standard input and sequently generates and prints all subsets to standard output. Note that this solution ***does not save*** the subsets, if it is not necessary:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void calcPowerSet( const std::vector< int >& inputSet )
{
    int n = inputSet.size();
    for( int ones = 0; ones <= n; ++ones )
    {
        std::vector< bool > mask( n, 0 );
        for( int i = 0; i < ones; ++i )
            mask[ i ] = true;           // setting first 'ones' bits to '1'
        do
        {   
           // printing the subset described by current mask
           std::cout << "(";
           for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
              if( mask[ i ] )
                  std::cout << ' ' << inputSet[ i ] << ' ';
           std::cout << ")\n";
        }
        while( std::next_permutation( mask.rbegin(), mask.rend() ) ); // generating masks
    }
}


int main ()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector< int > inputSet( n );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        std::cin >> inputSet[ i ];
    calcPowerSet( inputSet );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I like the concept of this algorithm, especially how space-efficient it is. Unfortunately, using `next_permutation` with the reversed iterators doesn't produce the desired order (test with `n = 4` and look at the subsets of size 2). Using `prev_permutation` with forward iterators works, however. Intuitively, there must be a way to get `next_permuation` to work as well, but it escapes me.